# Display a Spinner while loading Parent State Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React with typescript for my application. What I have now is in my top level “app.tsx” a state called objects which is an array of objects. I have passed down through a few child components a function that is getObjects which is defined in the top app level. This function returns the state object[] if it is defined otherwise calls an asynchronous function to load in the objects.

> What I would like to do is to display a loading spinner in my child component while this state object[] is still undefined in the app.

I know that if I were to load the object[] as a local state in my child component I could easily accomplish this. Is there any way that I can call a callback at the child level after the state in the app has finished loading? The only way that I see to do it is to pass the object[] itself to the child component, but my knowledge is still very limited. Thank you, I appreciate all help.

**Edit:**
I do need the getObjects function in my grandchild component. I've simplified the structure a bit. What really is the situation is in the app object is a Dictionary type that acts as a key-value pair with a number id corresponding to a specific array of objects. On app loading, one key-value pair is chosen and that is loaded asynchronously while the user can keep using the app. It loads in the backend for these initial child components so a spinner is not needed.

Later in the greatgrandchild component, there is a need to, if chosen by the user, load another id into the dictionary while using an API to populate the object[] portion of the dictionary. Once this portion of the dictionary is loaded, the getObjects call in the top app layer returns a converted array of objects in my greatgrandchild to be used for selection. What is happening now is that the selectbox is just being empty until the async function completes, then it populates as expected. What I would like to do is to display a spinner in the greatgrandchild in place of the selectbox while this operation completes.

Since the structure is a dictionary and technically two values for the dictionary could be trying to be loaded at a time, I'm not sure that I want to try to pass through and use a boolean for this loading.

I am reluctant to pass through the whole dictionary itself and wait for the particular dictionary key-value pair to be loaded since this seems like an anti-pattern. What is the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: You would have a `isLoading` state on the parent component that's passed down to the child component. Once the object fetch is completed, update the `loading` state and that's going to reflect on the child component.

Comment: @ShawnYap would this be better or easier than just passing the object[] down to my child component? This isLoading will be the case for multiple state arrays defined in the app, so would I have to either pass down multiple isLoading booleans or the arrays themselves?

Comment: I've posted a generic approach below. It'll only pass the object to the child once it's done loading.

Comment: @ShawnYap The reason I am reluctant is that I am mutliple layers down from my parent app. The children along the way do utliize the getObjects function, but not necessarily the loading spinner. I guess I am uneasy about passing a bunch of booleans that will not be utilized by these child components, but need to be passed through their props to the grandchildren etc

Comment: Hmm if that's the case, is there a reason why you don't want your getObjects function to be in the grandchild component?

Comment: Maybe a HOC that controls the state and then wrap that HOC onto any components that requires those states might be worth looking into.

Comment: @ShawnYap I have posted more context for my problem. It should probably have been in the initial post since it was very vague. I am new to react and have read a tiny bit about HOCs, but I am unsure of how to use them on this greatgrandchild component which has children of its own.

Answer (score 0):

In your child component conditionally render the spinner and the object contents.

```
{
yourObjectFromParent 
? (<>Your object contents here</>)
: (<LoaderComponent/>)
}
```

OR

You can try to set a state called loading=true in the parent and set it to false when object is loaded. You should pass this loading state as props to the child components. If thats the case your code will be like this. This can also be implemented with a global state handler like redux.

```
{
props.loading 
? (<>Your object contents here</>)
: (<LoaderComponent/>)
}
```

Comment: I am looking to do this without passing the object[] itself to my child component. Is that the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: If the object is empty, this would forever be loading.

Comment: You can also try to set a loading state on parent and pass it to the children.I have updated the answer @C.Programming .

Comment: @ShawnYap empty objects return true don't they ? I tried it just now and got true

Comment: @Muljayan What about some random cases where object is `null`?

Comment: In that case an error handling can be done, but its outside the scope of the question i guess.

Answer (score 0):

This would show a spinner until loading is completed.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
        isLoading: true,
        data: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchSomeData(url)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({isLoading: false, data: data});
      })
    }

    render() {
        const {isLoading, data} = this.state;
        return isLoading ? <ChildComponent data={data} /> : <Spinner />
    }
}
```